# 2015 MBP 12,1 Ubuntu installation - Keyboard issues

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, macbook

hoping for some help with my 2015mbp. It got donated to me, but I'm not a mac guy so figured I would install ubuntu to delve into the Linux world a bit. I've been going a little nuts trying to get the keyboard/trackpad to work. I've already tried following the guide [Text](https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver) to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit to provide more clarification. Installed Ubuntu 21.10, everything works as expected except for complete lack of functionality using the built in keyboard/touchpad.

Comment: The software on the link you posted is over 4 years old. When software is no longer maintained, it's generally not expected to work. In some cases, outdated unmaintained software can break your system. If you can explain the original problem maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Sorry, first time posting. The problem I am facing is the touchpad and keyboard aren't working at all. USB keyboard and mouse work no problem, but the built in keyboard/touchpad don't work at all.

Comment: Does it work in a live session (Try Ubuntu from USB) and did it work during system installation?

Comment: @Nmath, doesn't work in a live session or during system installation. Works in bootloader, and also works in the grub loader. As soon as it boots into OS no trackpad/keyboard